# Splitting text into an array of 4

Tags: c#, .net

I want to split text, using a char, so that I can create an object from it.

```
string s = "Domain_FieldName";
//string s = "Domain_Schema_TableName_FieldName";
//string s = "Domain_Schema_FieldName";

 var x = s.Split(new[] {'_'}, StringSplitOptions.None);

var xx = new Response()
{
  Value = "test",
  DataType = "string",
  Domain = 
  Schema = 
  TableName =
  FieldName = 
};
```

So, the issue is that the string to be split, could vary in length.

But I need the string to be split so that it could map to the response object fields.

I need to have a generic way to populate the response object.

So as an example, if only "Domain_FieldName" is specified, it needs to know to pass Domain to Domain on the response and FieldName to FieldName on the response, and Schema and TableName should get an empty string

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: What *exactly* is your question? It's clear to see that you're splitting `s` and assigning it to `x` - but where are you doing anything with `x`? What parts of `x` do you want to put into `xx`? Can't see what you're trying to do, sorry.

Comment: If you don't have a predefined series of data you can't achieve what you what. You may need something as this: Domain _ _ _FieldName. This way you will be sure that the 4th element is always the Fieldname, the first is always the domain and so on.

Comment: Please reformat your code sample(s). It is not just an inconvenience to potential readers, it could have the effect of driving them away. Formatting code matters, and posting badly formatted code sends a signal that the post is not worth it. Yours will not even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
        var x = s.Split(new[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        var xx = new Response
        {
            Value = "test",
            DataType = "string",
            Domain = x.Length > 0 ? x[0] : null,
            Schema = x.Length > 1 ? x[1] : null,
            TableName = x.Length > 2 ? x[2] : null,
            FieldName = x.Length > 3 ? x[3] : null
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use C# `Split` function

```
string s = "Domain_Schema_TableName_FieldName";
string[] substring= s.Split('_');
```

The above code will split the string `Domain_Schema_TableName_FieldName` into different parts using the delimiter `_` and will save the substrings in a string array called substring

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the length of the `split` Array, before setting variables. (And set a default value, if it's too short)

```
var xx = new Response()
{
  Value = "test";
  DataType = "string";
  Domain = (x.Length >= 1)?x[0]:"";
  Schema = (x.Length >= 2)?x[1]:"";
  TableName = (x.Length >= 3)?x[2]:"";
  FieldName = (x.Length >= 4)?x[3]:"";
```

};

(also: `s.Split("_")` or `s.Split('_')` would work just as well)

EDIT:
I didn't see, that you only wanted the last 4 fields filled. Changed code

2nd EDIT:
I also didn't see that the Order of strings may be different (i.e. Example 1 vs. Example 3) . In that case i can't help you unless you can specify, how to determine which string needs to go into which field.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        string s = "Domain_FieldName";
        var x = s.Split(new[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var xx = new Response
        {
           Value = "test",
           DataType = "string",
           Domain =x[0],
           Schema ="",
           TableName ="",
           FieldName = x[1]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

From your examples seems like Domain is always first, and FieldName always last:

```
string s = "Domain_FieldName";
//string s = "Domain_Schema_TableName_FieldName";
//string s = "Domain_Schema_FieldName";

var x = s.Split('_');

var xx = new Response()
{
  Value = "test",
  DataType = "string",
  Domain = x[0]
  Schema = x.Length > 2 ? x[1] : "";
  TableName = x.Length > 3 ? x[2] : "";
  FieldName = x.Length > 1 ? x.Last() : "";
};
```